# Gold mine that starts from first column

Tags: algorithm

I am looking at this [Gold mine problem.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gold-mine-problem/)

Given a gold mine of n*m dimensions. Each field in this mine contains a positive integer which is the amount of gold in tons. Initially the miner is at first column but can be at any row. He can move only (right->,right up /,right down) that is from a given cell, the miner can move to the cell diagonally up towards the right or right or diagonally down towards the right. Find out maximum amount of gold he can collect.

```
Examples: 
 

Input : mat[][] = {{1, 3, 3},
                   {2, 1, 4},
                  {0, 6, 4}};
Output : 12 
{(1,0)->(2,1)->(1,2)}

Input: mat[][] = { {1, 3, 1, 5},
                   {2, 2, 4, 1},
                   {5, 0, 2, 3},
                   {0, 6, 1, 2}};
Output : 16
(2,0) -> (1,1) -> (1,2) -> (0,3) OR
(2,0) -> (3,1) -> (2,2) -> (2,3)
```

This is the working code:

```
class GFG {
    static final int MAX = 100;
    static int getMaxGold(int gold[][],
                              int m, int n)
    {
        int goldTable[][] = new int[m][n];
        for (int col = n-1; col >= 0; col--)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
            {
                int right = (col == n-1) ? 0
                        : goldTable[row][col+1];
 
               int right_up = (row == 0 ||
                               col == n-1) ? 0 :
                        goldTable[row-1][col+1];
     
                int right_down = (row == m-1
                            || col == n-1) ? 0 :
                          goldTable[row+1][col+1];
     
                goldTable[row][col] = gold[row][col]
                 + Math.max(right, Math.max(right_up,
                                       right_down));
                                                         
            }
        }
        int res = goldTable[0][0];
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
            res = Math.max(res, goldTable[i][0]);
             
        return res;
    }
}
```

I understood this program clearly. But this code starts the for loop from last column `col = n-1`, so how can solve this task if I am starting from first column instead of last:

```
        for (int col = 0; col <n; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
            {

            }
        }
```

Is it possible to solve this problem if we start from first row and first column?

Comment: Yes, with exponential-time brute force recursion through all possibilities.

Comment: You can solve this problem by iterating in either direction. I don't see why you care which way the code iterates, unless you have failed to understand what it is doing.

Comment: @Beta, so you mean if I apply the same logic for max of 3 values that are right and updating the element will work even if I start from first column instead of last column?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, can you please share the pseudo-code for that.

Comment: @Beta, For input `{{1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 4}, {0, 6, 4}}` If I apply from first column, then in first iteration the array becomes`{{4, 3, 3}, {8, 1, 4}, {6, 6, 4}};`, now what will be the next step?

Comment: @learner: It's a bad algorithm, since as @Beta says it should be possible to solve this problem in the same O(mn) time complexity as the given solution by iterating forwards as the problem is left-right symmetrical. If you want to implement it as an exercise, then I'd suggest having function parameters `score` (integer) and `pos` (an array of (x, y) pairs, the last of which is the current position); the rest is best figured out yourself if you want to learn.

Comment: You appear to have failed to understand the algorithm. What do you think those numbers represent? After the first pass the array should be `{{1, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {0, 8, 4}}`, after the next it should be `{{1, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 12}, {0, 8, 12}}` and then we find the max of the last column: 12.

Comment: @Beta, Thanks clear now. `What do you think those numbers represent?`, I see the numbers as the amount of value collected to reach that element position. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct, for the numbers *behind* the advancing front.